# Laravel 5.7 Validation errors not showing

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following function below that is logging in fine and redirecting fine in both options however I am not getting any errors!!  - How can I also override the error messages?

**Blade:**

```
   <div>
      {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}
      {{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required')) }}

       <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</div>
```

**Function:**

```
public function processLogin() {

    // Lets create some simple validation rules for login

    $rules = array(

        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    );

    // Lets check the guest filled in all the correct details :)

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // Lets redirect back to login page if they have not

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password')); //Sends back only room name
    } else {
        // We will create an array of login information :)

        $loginData = array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Input::get('password'),
        );

        // Lets Login

        if (Auth::attempt($loginData)) {
            // If they logged in correct lets give them this :)

            return Redirect::away('https://google.co.nz/');
        } else {
            // If not they can have this

            return Redirect::to('/');
        }
    }
```

Comment: what error does it show?

Comment: @Capt.Teemo I am getting no errors but I also would like to override the default ones I do get

Answer (score 0):

in order to replace the error message, create an array for the custom messages:

```
    $customMessages = [
        'username.required' => 'Username cannot be empty.',
        'password.required' => 'Password cannot be empty.',
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules,$customMessages);
```

You can look at the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#customizing-the-error-messages).

Answer (score 0):

Validation rules:

```
$rules = [
                'username' => 'required',
                'password' => 'required',
            ];
```

Custom messages if validation fails

```
 $messages = ['username' => 'error with username.',
'password'=>'error with password.'];
```

Validate input with rules, adding in custom messages

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
```

Answer (score 0):

buddy, you don't pass any request parameter for that it's not working

```
public function processLogin(Request $request) {

// Let's create some simple validation rules for login

$rules = array(

    'username' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required',
);

// let's check the guest filled in all the correct details :)

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

// Let's redirect back to login page if they have not

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::to('/')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput(Input::except('password')); //Sends back only room name
} else {
    // We will create an array of login information :)

    $loginData = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password'),
    );

    // Lets Login

    if (Auth::attempt($loginData)) {
        // If they logged incorrect let's give them this :)

        return Redirect::away('https://google.co.nz/');
    } else {
        // If not they can have this

        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

don't forget to import request class

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

remove cache to give the following command on your terminal

```
php artisan config:cache 
php artisan view:clear 
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: okk fine don not be worry cause I am here
Now we are doing debugging
first you can check response data which come from you view(blade) file for example var_dump($request)
which data you showing just inform me or give me screenshot

Comment: Can you so me an example of how to dump in blade?

Comment: you just return $request 
you can see all the data that are you gave form your form 
if you don't see anything then definitely you were mismatch route ....
please inform me what data returning on the $request

Comment: I am getting nothing on request

Comment: that means your route is not working properly or your actiion attributes mismatch 
now we are fixing routing issue
go to the web and then route.php
or you can give the teamviewer id i will try to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so you are trying to change the "default" errors messages, and not create a new rule. I see some above have been answering but this is my 2 cents, very clean and simple.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $messages = [
        'username.required' => 'You must have a username!',
        'password.required' => 'Please add a password...'
    ];

    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ], $messages);

   // And here is the code that should be executed if the validation is valid

   return 'Everything seems to work!';
}
```